# Add fee to total order balance once

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to add fee to total order balance once, based on some conditions? The product pricing rules are added for each product. I need this to be a price component, so it needs to be displayed as fee on the total order display (not as an added product!).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, since the order total is calculated from the line items. Either you would need to add/remove a line item that has the fee, or you would need to add the price to the order after it has been loaded, using `hook_commerce_order_load`.

I would prefer the line item solution, as it is more robust, but it also requires more work, as you will need to define the line item and either create custom code for adding/removing it.